# MSI Stealth 17 - Ubuntu 22.04 - No WI-Fi Adapter Found (Killer wi-fi 6e ax1675i 160mhz wireless network adapter) - wifi not working

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04, iwlwifi

I purchased an [MSI Stealth 17 laptop](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/msi-stealth-17-3-240hz-qhd-gaming-laptop-intel-core-i9-13900h-nvidia-geforce-rtx-4090-2tb-ssd-64gb-memory-black/6532165.p?skuId=6532165) that comes with a killer(r) wi-fi 6e ax1675i 160mhz wireless network adapter.

I am dual booting Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with Windows 11. Kernel: 6.2.0-33-generic.

Wi-Fi works on windows but not on Ubuntu. Wired works. Everything works except the Wi-FI. It says `No Wireless Adapter Found` on the Wi-Fi settings page.

1. I have tried the [Linux drivers provided by Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html) and no go. I went through the manual firmware installation for 200/201/210.
2. I've read similar questions and none of the solutions work. I have followed them step by step.
3. I believe the key issue is below.

```
[ 3.881927] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev 51f1/1672, rev=0x370, rfid=0x2010d000
[ 3.881974] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
```

4. More information:

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51f1] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Rivet Networks Device [1a56:1672]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:51e8] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
--
2f:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Killer E3000 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:3000] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Killer E3000 2.5GbE Controller [1462:13bc]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

5. Should I just buy a USB wifi adapter?

Comment: Does this help? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/q/425155/1684306)

Comment: Was Windows hybrid shutdown disabled?

Comment: Hi - responding to you both. I’m using this machine purely for science purposes and do not have windows on it at all. Secure boot says disabled. I purchased a Wi-Fi adapter for now. I literally tried every solution mentioned. If you have anything new please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Linux kernel patch](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/f4daceae4087bbb3e9a56044b44601d520d009d2) your device would work with Linux kernel 6.5 or later.
Also, you could try an OEM kernel which [seems to have](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Ecanonical-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem/+git/jammy/tree/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/drv.c?h=Ubuntu-oem-6.1-6.1.0-1021.21#n687) the same fix by executing this command:

```
sudo apt install linux-oem-22.04c
```

Reboot after kernel install.

Comment: I don't know why but the site replaces ~ with %7E in the second link which is wrong

Comment: Trying now. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: @pikubuntu any updates?

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; Disable the "Turn on fast start (recommended)" option in Windows under Shutdown settings in the Windows "Control Panel/System Settings/Power Options/Change what the power buttons do"

**Update** After additional testing it was apparent that the issue was how Windows saves state on a shutdown vs restart and how Intel wifi HW/Drivers initialize. By turning off fast start on shut down in Windows my Linux OS would reliably start the iwlwifi driver.

For the record my system has the AX200 Intel Wifi HW.

Secure boot was a non sequitur and after finding reliable repo steps the state of secure boot did not matter. However if using unsigned drivers that would be a problem with Secure Boot. The iwlwifi driver that comes with the kernel would be signed in Ubuntu. While the issue can be reproduced the root cause is something that still needs to be ascertained or at least a tighter set of steps to reproduce need to be discovered since right now my only way to repo is to go to Windows, start Balders Gate 3, exit, shutdown with fast start option enabled in Windows then boot into linux and wifi does not work. I'll keep chasing this down as it is really annoying and it would be good to find a Linux side fix that does not require turning off options in Windows.

Comment: I was worried about having to disable secure boot. I can try that if all else fails.

Comment: If you want to use secure boot then one option is to sign the modules.   I had to do this for VMWare kernel mods that would otherwise require disabling secure boot. Here is the process I used https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot. However it looks like there might be a newer way using update-secureboot-policy ( https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot )

Comment: I removed windows and I’m just using Ubuntu 22.04. If you have any other ideas lmk.